# Graph API error param data must be an array

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to load some data to facebook offline events using graph API explorer but ends up with error:

```
{"error": {
    "message": "(#100) param data must be an array.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Arug9LHzE4FKTY67LrqQZiJ"
  }
}
```

My data is already in array format.

Comment: Please include the request you are trying to make - without the access token, of course.